# 301 redirect to same name file, same server, but differnet domain name

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I recently did an overhaul of a website in which we switched to a new master domain name for that website.  The old domain is still active, and needed to be redirected to the new domain name.

The site still has the same root folder, and so there are a couple of files that were updated, but have the same name (i.e. index.php, about.php, contact.php).

I manually redirected all the files (via .htaccess) that no longer exist to new files with a manual redirect:

```
redirect 301 /old_file.php http://www.new_domain.org/new_file.php
```

However this will not work with the files that have the same name such as "index.php".  I can still call the site by the old domain name.  How do I properly refer these files so that I don't have a duplicate penalty from google?

I tried this and it did not work:

```
#Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.old_domain.org$[OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old_domain.org$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.new_domain.org/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Thank You

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Clear your browser cache and restart it
- Make sure mod_rewrite and .htaccess are enabled through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

Code

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?old_domain\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.new_domain.org%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at using the canonical tag as an alternative.

http://www.seomoz.org/blog/cross-domain-canonical-the-new-301-whiteboard-friday

Comment: I like what this option does with allowing others to use your information, yet you still get the search credit, however for our situation where we are going away from an old domain name completely I'd rather do a direct refer...you did just give me an idea for our site though, as quite a bit of our content can easily be used by others yet still refer back to us...in fact that's a direction we were wanting to head, so Thank you for this link